# How to show the YouTube upload date when using zoomed browser?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I use Windows with medium fonts (125%) and Chrome set at 125% zoom level.  With these settings, the upload date on YouTube pages isn't shown because there is not enough room to fit it in the space provided.

How can I use CSS (maybe JavaScript too if required) in a Chrome extension to modify the page so that the upload date shows?

Thank you.

Comment: I would collapse elements like SHARE/SAVE to just icons which might be enough for the date to show up. As for a JS solution, see [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I ended up removing the Save button completely using CSS (code is in my answer).  I never used the Save feature so for me this seems to be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the following CSS:

```
#top-level-buttons > ytd-button-renderer:nth-child(4){ display:none; }
```

It removes the Save button from the button menu (I don't use it anyway) and so makes room for the upload date.  Seems to work perfectly.